# awk sed rename files with indexation in them

Tags: linux, awk, sed, rename

I have multiple files in a folder named by following a sequence such as :

```
im.0001.jpeg
im.0006.jpeg
im.0011.jpeg
im.0016.jpeg

etc
```

how can I rename them in order to have this :

```
im.0001.jpeg
im.0002.jpeg
im.0003.jpeg
im.0004.jpeg

etc
```

ps: currently the indexation change between numbers is 5 but this could vary

Comment: Are there any potential name collisions as you rename a file to a name that already exists?

Answer (score 3):

Like this, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf "%.4d", ++$main::c/e' ./im*.jpeg
rename(./im.0006.jpeg, ./im.0002.jpeg)
rename(./im.0011.jpeg, ./im.0003.jpeg)
rename(./im.0016.jpeg, ./im.0004.jpeg)
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

There's no `im.0001.jpeg` because it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=$(printf '%s\n' im.*.jpeg)

index=1

for file in $files
do
  mv "$file" "im.$(printf '%04d' $index).jpeg"
  index=$((index+1))
done
```

Comment: Don't parse `ls` output but use `globs`: `printf '%s\n' *.jpeg | sort -n`.

Comment: The default behavior of `printf` is already to sort. No need `sort -n` with this zero padded digits

Answer (score 0):

you asked for sed/awk, so propably doesn't want loops etc. ... try this:

```
printf "%s\n" *|awk -F . '{ if ($2==NR) next;printf "mv %s im.%4.4i.jpeg\n",$0,NR}'|sh
```

careful with the checking for equal source and destination name, as it currently relies upon the dots surrounding current numbering.

If possible errors (when current numbering may already fit for the first lines) doesn't disturb your private peace, you can eliminate `if ($2==NR) next;` and evtl. drop error output (by appending `&2>-` or `&2>/dev/null`)